# Is there a way to expose an NSArray<NSValue> of CGPoint as [CGPoint] to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, core-graphics

I have this property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray<NSValue *> *vertices;
```

where the vertices are of type `CGPoint`.

I know swift has some convenient language features such as NS_SWIFT_NAME to change the function names, but I wonder if there is a way to expose that property as [CGPoint] type in Swift.

I am asking on how to do this in objective-c syntax, how to create an objective-c API that exposes "vertices" as a [CGPoint] when used in Swift.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want here Obj C solution of above array ?

Comment: yes, i want an objc solution that will display in swift as [CGPoint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write, in Obj-C, a property that is of type `[CGPoint]` in Swift.

What you can do is annotate your `vertices` property with `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT`. This will expose it to Swift as a property named `__vertices` instead. Now you can write an extension on your class in Swift that provides its own `var vertices: [CGPoint]` computed property. It might look like

```
var vertices: [CGPoint] {
    return __vertices.map({ $0.cgPointValue })
}
```

The downside to this approach is every time you access the `vertices` property from Swift it will have to allocate a brand new array. But there's not really any way around that if you want to expose a `[CGPoint]` (besides trying to see if you can implement any sort of caching behavior, where you only create the new `[CGPoint]` if the original `NSArray<NSValue *>` changed).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need above CGPoint array in Obj-C so you can use CGPoint array like this :

```
self.vertices = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 10)],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10, 20)]];
```

for get back that point :

```
CGPoint pointValue = [self.vertices[0] CGPointValue];
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: i think u misunderstood my questions what I am asking on how to do this in objective-c syntax, how to create an objective-c API that exposes "vertices" as a [CGPoint] when used in Swift.